# Can't solve this mixed content issue

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, mixed-content

I have an issue when loading a `js` file: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js`, which I load like this on my webpage:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Indeed, when I load my webpage I see this error in my firefox console:

> Mixed active content «
>   http://ipinfo.io/?callback=jQuery1111014566829645093016_1495038438100&_=1495038438101
>   »   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4:26952

So, I tried several solutions to solve this,

I replaced `https://` with `//` in the `src` attribute of the `script` tag, but did not work.

Then I suspected that the problem is that I am trying (indirectly) to load `http://ipinfo.io` etc. from my `https` page, so I changed all `http` occurences with `https` in `jquery-1.11.1.min.js`, but still nothing.

There this indication of an offset "**4:26952**" for the `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` file, but I can't figure out how to find it and what it means exactly (4th line, 26952 column ? but how do I find it ?)

Thank you

Comment: It'll be easier to hunt down the error if you load `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>` while you're debugging.

Comment: @jameslafferty It's what I did, but I still have the same error

Comment: The main issue is that your page is HTTPS but it's requesting an HTTP URL (`http://ipinfo.io`) through a JSONP request. Until you fix that, it'll keep logging the mixed content warning.

Comment: @aurelSon but where's the error in the non-minified version of jQuery?

Comment: You have a jsonp request  somewhere that is pointing to http rather than https.  This cannot be solved by editing the jquery source file (nor should you).

Comment: @James Ok but how do I find this jsonp request ?

Comment: I would "search in files" for "ipinfo.io".  It looks like ipinfo.io has no problem with https requests so it'd be a quick change of http to https in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think so

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

contains like

```
http://ipinfo.io
```

So look for `http://ipinfo.io` and change it to

```
https://ipinfo.io
```

and it should work fine ...